# Is my answer correct? Sequence limit

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm preparing for my test and I want to ask if my answer is correct.

> What is the limit of this sequence: $\displaystyle\ b _{n} =  \frac{3 ^{\sqrt{n}} }{2^n}$?

First, I used the Stolz–Cesàro theorem:

$$\frac{a _{n+1}-a_n}{c_{n+1}-c_n} =  \frac{3 ^{\sqrt{n+1}} - 3 ^{\sqrt{n}} }{2^{n+1} - 2^n} = \frac{3 ^{\sqrt{n+1}} - 3 ^{\sqrt{n}} }{2^n}$$

Then the Squeeze theorem:
$$0 \leftarrow 0  \le  \frac{3 ^{\sqrt{n+1}} - 3 ^{\sqrt{n}} }{2^n}  \le \frac{3 ^{\sqrt{n+1}} }{2^n} \rightarrow 0$$

Therefore the limit of $b_n = 0$

Is this enough or should I add something? Thank you in advance.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can have a vastly easier proof: $\sqrt{n} \le \frac n 2$ for all $n \ge 4$, and so $0 \le b_n \le 2^{-n/2} \to 0$ gives the result.

Comment: $b_n=\frac{3^\sqrt{n}}{4^\sqrt{n}}}$